# Entity Framework returns 0 items

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

I`m using Entity Framework 6.1.3.

When i try to get values from database table it returns me 0 items but in database are 9 rows.

And Entity FrameWork invokes the OnModelCreating method.

I searched all internet but nothing found how to fix that.

My DbContext class

```
namespace TestTask.Models
{
    using System;
    using System.Data.Entity;
    using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;

    public partial class Entities : DbContext
    {
        public Entities()
            : base("MenuItemsContainer")
        { }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder) 
        { 

        modelBuilder.Properties() 
                    .Where(p => p.Name == "Id") 
                    .Configure(p => p.IsKey()); 
        } 

        public virtual DbSet<DataMenuItemSet> DataMenuItemSet { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<ItemsSet> ItemsSet { get; set; }
    }
}
```

My DataMenuItemSet class

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace TestTask.Models
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public partial class DataMenuItemSet
    {
        public DataMenuItemSet()
        {
            this.ItemsSet = new HashSet<ItemsSet>();
        }

        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public bool IsRoot { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> Parent { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<ItemsSet> ItemsSet { get; set; }
    }
}
```

All of this is generated with Entity Framework.

I need to get values from database.

***Updated***

I`ve solved the problem.

The point is that i have two projects in my solution. First is a site, that have the model from database, and second is simple ConsoleApplication, where i tried to test a database data. When i trying to connect to db via dbcontext from the other application its not working as described above. To make it work, I transfered a connection string from Web Site application, that have edmx model and dbcontext, to application, where i were testing this connection and data.

Here is how it works

[image]

Yellow - ConsoleApplication
Red - Web Site with model and dbcontext

[image]

Here is a model and Web.config
I transfered the connection string from Web.config to the App.cofig of ConsoleApplication, and the model.

[image]

ConsoleApplication with transfered model and connection string.

And after all that it works for me.

Thanks for help !!!

Comment: context.TableName.toList()

Comment: What options did you use when you initially generated you context? E.g. empty code first, model first from designer, etc. Can you post your connection string?

Comment: I generated model from database.
Connection string : 'metadata=res://*/Models.DataMenuItems.csdl|res://*/Models.DataMenuItems.ssdl|res://*/Models.DataMenuItems.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient'

Comment: You're going to jump through hoops trying to deploy the LocalDB. You might want to install mssql express and set it as your default in vs. You might also try using a model instance of the type DataMenuItemSet. That should allow you to do something like: application.Models.DataMenuItemSet dmis = new application.Models.DataMenuItemSet(); string myvar = dmis.Name;

Comment: What code are you using to try to get the rows from the database? All you have in your question is the auto generated code that enables you to access the database. I see nothing that actually queries the database.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the very common way to get data from db using entity framework and LINQ query.

```
using (var context = new Entities())
{
    var L2EQuery = from item in context.DataMenuItemSet
                   where item.IsRoot == true
                   select item;

    var result = L2EQuery.ToList()<DataMenuItemSet>;
 }
```

Hope will be helpful.

Comment: I tried this one. But it still returns me 0 elements.